# XPages Repeat control, compute visible

Tags: repeater, xpages

I have global context document currentDoc and repeat control with responses of currentDoc.
In repeat control i have 2 fields: 
1) ComboBox
2) Editbox, with computed Visible by ComboBox:

```
var temp = respDoc.getItemValueString( "Combobox1");
return temp == "a";
```

Onchange event ComboBox i update repeat control.
And i have button "Add response" (create/save response and update repeat control)
Its work. But.. if i create response and save this, field with computed Visible reset to "" and not saved. If i re-enter text to Editbox and re-saved, then Ok. Only works after re-saving. Have not errors.
May be you know, what problem?

### Source code

```
<xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="curDoc" formName="test"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="respDoc"
        repeatControls="false"
        indexVar="respDocIndex" value="#{javascript:return curDoc.getDocument().getResponses();}">
        <xp:panel id="panel1">
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:150.0px">
                        <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" style="width:95%"
                            value="#{respDoc.combobox}" required="false">
                            <xp:selectItem
                                itemLabel="Email" itemValue="a">
                            </xp:selectItem>
                            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="UserName"
                                itemValue="b">
                            </xp:selectItem>

                            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:comboBox>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                    <xp:inputText id="inputText2"
                        value="#{respDoc.editbox}" maxlength="20">
                        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript://return true    <---- if uncomment it, then all work
var temp = respDoc.getItemValueString( "combobox");
return temp == "b";}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                    </xp:inputText></xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:button value="Save" id="button4">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:respDoc.save();}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:repeat>
    <xp:button value="Add Response" id="button2">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">

            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(curDoc.isNewNote())
    curDoc.save();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "test");
doc.makeResponse(curDoc.getDocument());
doc.save();}]]></xp:this.action>

        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

Comment: Post more of your source code. Most likely it's an issue with the way your data sources are defined, but it's difficult to determine just from a description of the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach has a number of issue:

1. A server roundtrip is initiated on the change of a checkbox, which is an unexpected behavior for a form
2. A document that has not been saved can't have responses, so you shouldn't show the repeat
3. When you create a new document you don't assign the "combobox" item any value,so your test `temp =="b"` fails.
4. When no rendered, no value is send back to the server, that might not be what you want

I would use `style="display : none" to hide the field on the client side and have the event only run on the client. also add a value to your combobox when creating a new document:`

```
 var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
 doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "test");
 doc.makeResponse(curDoc.getDocument());
 doc.replaceItemValue("Combobox1","a");
 doc.save();
 doc.recyle();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Perhaps IBM should revise the properties and allow us formulas for "rendered" and "visible" that are separate as part of the object instead of requiring HTML styling to hide things?

Comment: Visible *is* a) a HTML property in the HTML standard and b) can be computed in the style property. So what are you missing? It, there you are right, initially confusing that the rendered property is labelled 'visible' in the DDE UI

Comment: @stwissel Exactly. It is labelled "Visible" but is more correctly identified as "rendered" in source. I think they really ought to use "visible" for whether it displays and "rendered" for whether it is included on the XPage. That is, split the current muddling of terminology. Failing that, they should change the property name in the DDE UI to be labelled "Rendered" instead of "Visible".

Comment: Short of that a Beginner would have no clue what rendering is ;-).  And once you are at the level that you do,  you most likely use the all properties panel or the source view exclusively and there it is correctly called rendered. The label in the pretty panel was very consciously choosen to lower the starting hurdles (rendered is new to Domino developers). If that's a problem for you,  stick to the all properties panel